# What is the time complexity of the following code fragment for Stock Buy & Sell?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, time-complexity

Recently I was trying the problem of Stock Buy and Sell in which we can buy a stock on any day and sell it on any upcoming day, and we have to find the maximum profit that we can get.

The solution that first came to my mind was the code below but I'm not able to determine its time complexity. It would be very helpful if you can help with this.

```
int maxProfit(int price[], int start, int end){
  if(end<=start)
    return 0;

  int profit=0;

  for(int i=start; i<end; i++){

    for(int j=i+1; j<=end; j++){

      if(price[j]>price[i]){

        int curr_profit=price[j]-price[i]+maxProfit(price,start,i-1)+maxProfit(price,j+1,end);
        profit=max(profit,curr_profit);
      }
    }

    return profit;
  }
}
```

Comment: The loops are O^2, and the two recursive calls just make things worse. At this point it's pointless to attempt to figure out the final complexity. Describing it as "bad", is sufficient.

Comment: Just wanted to know coz I read for few hours but couldn't find something related to this. Some say its some sort of binary recursion but that also didn't help. Can the time complexity for this code be figured out using recursive tree?

Comment: I'm guessing its n^4. `maxProfit` probably need to cache it's already calculated values. Should bring it down to n^2

Comment: These kinds of puzzles from various online coding/hacking/competion sites do absolutely nothing to help anyone towards the goal of learning C++. The correct solution for this problem will be O(n), and not require any recursion. Just three loops, and two temporary vectors (of tuples) to store the intermediate results. You won't find the information on the computer algorithms that are used to solve these puzzles on the aforementioned various online coding/hacking/competion sites, but only in a textbook, on this subject matter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that it can be solved in linear time but the thing that is worth learning from this fragment of code is to accurately determine the time complexity and really I haven't seen such problem of time complexity. This is the only reason I asked. ( I didn't asked for optimal Solution)

Comment: @sp2danny Can you please tell that how it can be n^4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it gives you **Ω(n!)**
if we focus only on `maxProfit(price,j+1,end)` :
At the beginning, the number of elements is n.
At each iteration we have two loop that call `maxProfit(price,j+1,end)` by decreasing the number of elements by 1.
We get :
**n^2 (the 2 first loop) * (n-1)^2 (the first call) * (n-2)^2 (the second call) * (n-3)^2 * ... * (n-n-1)^2**
this gives **O(n!)**.

Because i ignored the `maxProfit(price,start,i-1)` wich give also an additional complexity, so i thought that it will be better to use **Ω(n!)** to say that it take at least n!.

Comment: i am not sure about it, but i think it is not possible. if we take a simple case with `A: maxProfit(price,start,i-1) + B: maxProfit(price,j+1,end)` ==> complexity(A) + complexity(B), each time we call, we multiple , but also we add.  This generate a tree,  so when we descend in prefedeur we multiply, but at the same level we just add. at the leaf level, we get (n!) * (number of all paths).  so it depend on the final number of paths, which seem to me be (n)  (not sure about it). at the end , you get something like O(n*n!).  not sure as i said, you have to check all this.

Comment: But, anyway , n!  is horrible complexity , and no one work with this. so simply, search for another solution (algorithm) if they exist, else, go for approximate solution.  good luck.